# Query all columns with the amount I need, based on the tier

Tags: sql

I have a table with multiple columns, one of them called **Tier** which has values `A,B,C...` with `A` being the highest priority.

For example, there are 3 data in tier A, 2 in tier B, 1 in tier C.
If I need ~3 data, I'll get only data from tier A; if 4~5 data, get A+B, if 6, get all A+B+C. And I want to get all columns include tier in the table.

I know `CASE WHEN` might be needed in my query, but don't know how to combine it with `COUNT` and `WHERE`statements.

| Name | year | tier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | 1976 | A |
| Billy | 1986 | A |
| Brad | 1998 | A |
| Cindy | 2001 | B |
| Danny | 1999 | B |
| Eric | 1989 | C |

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting, sample data and desired results will help.

Comment: so... use `select top x .... order by tier` or `select .... order by tier limit x` (depends on your rdbms)

Comment: just adding a short sample.
The tier in my real data is not that simple as ABC, I do have to sort them by myself.
Is there a way to simplify the process?

Comment: "The tier in my real data is not that simple as ABC" - well, if it's sortable it doesn't change anything. If it's not, you'll need a way to sort it.

Comment: How do you determine the order?  Without an order, you have no highest or lowest priority.  Please add that detail to the question.